# YouTube-Api Comment on videos

Tags: ios, http, post, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to comment on a youtube video via the youtube api. I have to send some XML to their server, but when i do it gives me nothing back, neither comments it on the video.

Heres the [link to the api documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol)!

> POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: gdata.youtube.com
>
> Content-Type: application/atom+xml
>
> Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
>
> Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
>
> GData-Version: 2
>
> X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<content>This is a crazy video.</content>
</entry>
```

I really appreciate all your help, because I'm stuck on this for days.
Thanks!

Here is my code:
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

```
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\"><content>%@</content></entry>", [textField text]];

NSData *postData = [requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4NE7Nmmt0R4/comments"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"key=AI39si4apF3QyQkXbH_C5IHIClkyP2mio2QJ3JBUUpvPbO2rhch7tpYjMavZgt5QzGaGrHBfom5mNpoUq_ZLRPPa35KO21O9Pw" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GData-Key"];
[request setValue:@"2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

[conn start];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube API will **always** send an HTTP response whenever you make an HTTP request. Even if you make a completely invalid HTTP request, you'll get back an HTTP error response. Please double-check to see if you're getting any response back at all. If you're really not, then my guess is that you're not actually completing your HTTP request—perhaps it's never making it to the API servers due to some network problems, or perhaps you're not calculating `CONTENT_LENGTH` correctly (assuming you're attempting to calculate it by hand).

Also, I'd recommend using the [GData Objective-C client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) if you're not already.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Are you familiar with objective c? Then can see my code at the top (because I cant post it here) and maybe you see what is wrong. Normally it should work, because when i send a post request for a refresh token it works.

Comment: I'm not fluent in Objective-C, but the info I provided in my response still applies. Your best bet is to use the official client library if you can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: My first try was using the GData Objective-C library, but it is deprecated.

Comment: You need to use the YouTube GData API v2 to post comments, since v3 doesn't support that. I wouldn't shy away from using the client library.

Comment: The latest version i can find is 1.9.1. Could you provide me a link?

Comment: You can check out the latest version of the GData Objective-C client library from http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout

Comment: If you take a look at the code above, do you think I am missing something? Content-Length, Content-Type, Developer Key, GData-Version...

Comment: Oh yeah I got it to work! And now it also gives me something back, but it says Token invalid. Any idea?

Comment: And now <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ParseException</code><internalReason>Element type "entry" must be followed by either attribute specifications, "&gt;" or "/&gt;".</internalReason></error></errors>

Comment: Token invalid normally refers to using an incorrect developer key. It sounds like you're also sending in bad XML.